# SQL Server Date Comparison from string to datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using a SQL Server 2016 database and in my stored procedure I want to compare two dates.

I get one date parameter as string in 'dd-MM-yyyy' format.

```
@stringdate = '28-12-1990'   // I get date in this format
```

I want to convert this to date format and compare with a database column which is of type `datetime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **CAST()** function to convert to date format.

**Try this Code:**

```
CAST(dbdatetimecolumnname AS date) = (CAST(RIGHT(@stringdate,4) + '-' + LEFT(RIGHT(@stringdate,7),2) + '-' + LEFT(@stringdate,2) AS DATE))
```

**Right()** & **Left()** functions are used rearrange your string date format to db date format.

Answer (score 3):

Since you're on SQL Server **2016**, you could use the `PARSE` function and define the culture needed to successfully parse this string.

Something like

```
DECLARE @stringdate VARCHAR(20) = '28-12-1990';
DECLARE @parseddate DATETIME2(3);

SELECT @parseddate = PARSE(@stringdate AS DATE USING 'de');
SELECT @parseddate
```

I used the `de` culture for Germany - since the format of the date you have is a **European** format (`dd-MM-yyyy`).

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
set dateformat dmy
declare @d datetime='31-01-2016'
select @d
go


set dateformat ymd

declare @d datetime='31-01-2016'
select @d
go
```

Comment: No, this won't work. Just now see that parameter is string not `DateTime`. Sorry.